# Is there a way to generate a slice of bytes filled with a specific character?

Tags: go

I want to dynamically generate a slice of bytes and prefill them with a a value. In this case, if difficulty is 3, I want to generate `[]byte("000")`.

I have the working code below, is there anyway to optimize this into a one-liner? (i.e. initialize it and not have to run a for loop and set each element manually)?

```
var targetPrefix []byte = make([]byte, difficulty)

for i := 0; i < difficulty; i++ {
  targetPrefix[i] = 48 // UTF8 encoding for "0"
}
```

Comment: That's basically what you do. One thing to keep in mind with Go is they specifically designed the language to be minimalistic. There's pretty much one way to do something (using the base language), and that's it. No wasting time over "should I use a for loop?, should I X?, should I Y? It's a design decision the Go team made from the beginning.

Note: While I support poy's answer, the source for `bytes.Repeat` is essentially no different than your for loop, but it does look nicer. EDIT: I'll try to find the presentation where Pike illustrates this.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear Thanks, i am still pretty new to go so I am just hacking around for now. I will read Effective Go one of these weekends. If you can send me that presentation, it would be great!

Comment: https://youtu.be/rFejpH_tAHM?t=306 The whole video is a good one to watch, but here's the specific illustration I was referring to.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear That's awesome. Language design is an art

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess it depends what you mean by optimize. If you mean performance, then no not really. Ultimately when you "request" some memory, it would have to be iterated across to set the values. This was often more noticeable when writing C/C++ after using `malloc`. If you looked at the contents of the memory, it might be a bunch of 0s, but its likely to be a bunch of random values.

If however you mean to just write less code and utilize something that already exists you could take a look at [bytes.Repeat](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Repeat):

```
targetPrefix := bytes.Repeat([]byte("0"), difficulty)
```

Comment: Thanks, I meant write less code. I have used a lot of ruby in the last few years so I was hoping you could pass in the value you want each byte to intitalize to in the make function or something

Comment: @Huy OK, here's your one liner: `targetPrefix := bytes.Repeat([]byte("0"), difficulty)`

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'll add that to the answer

Comment: Thank you. I will accept when the 10 minute window allows me to :)